# How can I get a "Are you sure you want to quit YES/NO" prompt on an access button

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have a quit button in Access 2007 called cmdQuit -

How I can have it so it brings up a warning prompt along the lines of 
are you sure you want to quit? YES/NO

So that it doesn't just automatically quit the log form?

I have this as my command:

Private Sub cmdQuit_Click()

```
If MsgBox("Are you sure that you want to close this form?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    Cancel = True
End If
```

End Sub

So the No part of the prompt works but the Yes and then quit part does not

Thanks
Dan

Comment: Where are you closing the form? I.e. where are you calling `DoCmd.Close`?

Comment: The form is used repeatedly for quick logging into a SQL database so it doesn't actually have a natural close point. If I remove the above code then the quit button just closes as expected.

So do i need to set up a command in the button itself?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to cancel, so all you need is this:

```
Private Sub cmdQuit_Click()

If MsgBox("Are You Sure You Want To Close This Logger?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, PraiseLogger) = vbYes Then 
    DoCmd.Quit 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it now - it was as follows:

Private Sub cmdQuit_Click()

If MsgBox("Are you sure that you want to close this form?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
    DoCmd.Quit
Else
    Cancel = True
End If

End Sub

Had Exit Sub instead of the Quit command

Thanks
Dan

Answer (score 0):

There was also another way of doing it which made it a bit cleaner and didn't give me the "Microsoft Access" part at the top of the prompt

Private Sub cmdQuit_Click()

If MsgBox("Are You Sure You Want To Close This Logger?", vbYesNoCancel, PraiseLogger) = vbYes Then
DoCmd.Quit
Else: Cancel = True
End If

End Sub

Thanks
Dan